# How to avoid bash/shell skipping quotation in variable value?

Tags: json, bash, shell, variables, jq

I have set a variable like this below-

```
domain= ("*.abc" "*.xyz" "*.123")
```

I want set the value of this variable in a json file like below-

```
"Items": [
            "*.abc",
            "*.xyz",
            "*.123",]
```

But, the problem is bash script is skipping quotation "" and taking only inside the quotation. Other than this, bash is also trying to take the value as command. I just want to set the value in Items array including commas, that's it.

I am using `jq --arg e1 ${domain[@]}` to set the domain variable to e1 environment variable.

And getting this below error -

```
jq: error: syntax error, unexpected '*', expecting $end (Windows cmd shell quoting issues?) at <top-level>, line 1: *.xyz.com
```

Comment: If you want to have a quote as part of the string, you have to actually write one into the string, for instance `domain= ('"*.abc"' '"*.xyz"' '"*.123"')`.

Comment: @user1934428: The space after `=` produces a syntax error.

Comment: Ah, of course. I was stupidly copying from the original program. Of course it must be `domain=('"*.abc"' '"*.xyz"' '"*.123"')`. I assume the space was not present in the original code of the OP as well, otherwise execution would not even have reached the `jq` statement.

Comment: Bash or "shell"? Please read the descriptions of all the tags you applied!

Comment: space isn't there in original code, I tried with this ' ' but it's not working for jq as jq will append it for array string in Items

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could turn the bash array into a string and separate the items by, say, a newline character, then import the string using `--arg`, and split it up again into a jq array using `/`:

```bash
jq -n --arg e1 "$(printf '%s\n' "${domain[@]}")" '{Items: ($e1 / "\n")}'
```

```json
{
  "Items": [
    "*.abc",
    "*.xyz",
    "*.123"
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`--arg` doesn't understand bash arrays (some shells don't have any arrays).

You can use `--args` instead which populates `$ARGS.positional` with a list of remaining arguments.

```bash
domain=("*.abc" "*.xyz" "*.123")
jq '.Items = $ARGS.positional' <<<'{"Items":[]}' --args "${domain[@]}"
```

Note that I removed the space after `domain=`. With the space, bash throws a syntax error.

Comment: or even shorter: `jq -n '.Items = $ARGS.positional' --args "${domain[@]}`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `--args` to pass the array to `jq` as arguments, preserving the list/array structure:

```
domain=('*.abc' '*.xyz' '*.123')
jq -n --args '.Items = $ARGS.positional' "${domain[@]}"
```

Gives:

```
{
  "Items": [
    "*.abc",
    "*.xyz",
    "*.123"
  ]
}
```

Note that all the quoting is for the shell, not for the JSON. `jq` adds the quotes in the JSON. Add `> myfile` to `jq` to redirect the output to a file.

You can also skip the array and write `'*.123'` and so on directly, as arguments to `jq`.

Comment: jq: error: syntax error, unexpected QQSTRING_START, expecting $end (Windows cmd shell quoting issues?) at <top-level>, line 1:
.Items =$ARGS.positional "${domain[@]}"              
jq: 1 compile error

Comment: The syntax is correct. You have quoting issues. The syntax in your error is different from my example. Make sure to leave spaces and quotes exactly as the example. `"${domain[@]}"` shouldn't be in the jq command string, it should be after it. The error also says Windows cmd shell? The example is for bash.